# Using Android Room without immutable types (no Strings)

Tags: android, kotlin, jvm, android-room

For security compliance reasons (PCI) I need to access the data inside a Room (SQLite) database without using strings. Preferably as a ByteArray or CharArray. This is so that I can clear the buffer after using it. Is this even possible?

I have looked into `encryptedSharedPreferences` from JetPack, and they also seem to only support reading/writing immutable like Strings

My goal is to have

```
@entity
data class entity{
  val key: CharArray
}
```

populated without using type converters that utilised strings (or other immutable types that require the garbage collector to clean)